# IntelliJ Test Code Coverage not displayed in code

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

I'm coming from Eclipse, where code coverage is very conveniently displayed in the code as well as a table when running JUnit tests.

In IntelliJ, I thus far have no idea how to get this working, and some of the things that I have tried seem to differ from the manual.

I have a suite of test cases, and try to run them using "Run with Coverage". What I am used to from Eclipse is that after the test run, a coverage report is shown and that the covered lines in the code are displayed in green, and uncovered lines are displayed in red.

However, this does not happen. No coverage report is shown, and no lines are highlighted. This differs from the behaviour described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html

What do I have to do in order to have coverage data displayed both in code and as a statistics in InetlliJ?

---

EDIT: Added test run configuration
[image: Test Run Configuration]

---

EDIT 2:
For reference, this is how my Ceal-Delve project looks like when I run the tests in Eclipse. I would expect that IntelliJ also supports code coverage like this. At the very least I have found images, documentations and settings that all imply that something like this should also work in IntelliJ.
[image: Eclipse Code Coverage Sample]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your project structure. For example, for maven project it will work automatically.

Check you **Run/Edit Configurations** settings window:

[image]

Comment: I added my test run configuration above to compare. From what I can tell, if anything, it should be more elaborate. Also, we're using gradle. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: @KiraResari 1. Try please the sampling runner, tracing depends on your using tools (JaCoCo runner, for example). 2. Try to specify the any real package and check the coverage.

Comment: 1.) I tried the option "Sampling" at first, and that didn't display anything either, so I switched to "Tracing" which did not display anything as well. As expected, switching back again did not change anything about this.  2.) I also specified the exact package path that I wanted to be covered now, but it didn't change anything either.

Comment: @KiraResari Could you create the github repo with small code piece? (pom.xml and source directorier) because now it's hard to advice more..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ 2023.2.5 (Community Edition) MAC JDK11 (temurin). To get the code coverage to show for test classes (Cucumber Stepdef stuff) using JUnit I had to do: Run->Edit Configuration->Modify options (top right)-> Collect coverage in test folders. Then the coverage showed up:

[image: Modify otpions dropdown]